# How can we vertically align text in edit box?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created an editbox as:

```
m_EditWnd.Create(m_hWnd, rect, NULL, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_CHILD |
                                     WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
                 WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING);
```

There is a style for horizontal alignment as ES_CENTER for horizontal text alignment, but can we align text vertically centered?

Comment: see https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/devstudio_macros/textoperations/article.php/c8491/Vertical-Text-Centering-in-an-Edit-Control.htm

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, so here's a possibly useful snippet to a very old question!

If you supply the `WS_BORDER` style then the text gets automatically vertically centred, as requested. Since the OP is using `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`, a border is drawn *anyway*, so adding in this style shouldn't be a problem.

However, `WS_BORDER | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` only achieves a "partial" vertical centring.

Using `WS_BORDER | WS_EX_STATICEDGE` achieves the proper, vertical centring, although obviously then we have a slightly different visual style to the client-edged style. For me, I could live with this minor trade-off, rather that write a custom edit control.

Comment: Looks like an answer to the question to me.

Comment: Upon experimentation I can see that WS_EX_STATICEDGE is changing the border appearance but it does nothing for vertical centering.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution from @Aidan Ryan with a small adjustment to avoid another the issue related to UI. I move the "SetWindowPos" into the OnNCPaint() and invoke the function only once time.