# Inherited CEdit Control (for vertical centered Text) behaves strange

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I am using the code in the first answer of this question: [How can we vertically align text in edit box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867207/how-can-we-vertically-align-text-in-edit-box) to center the text in a CEdit control vertically.

Here is the used Class `CEditVC`

```
/// HEADER //////////////////////////////////////////

class CEditVC : public CEdit
{
public:
    CEditVC();

protected:
    CRect m_rectNCBottom;
    CRect m_rectNCTop;

public:
    virtual ~CEditVC();

protected:
    afx_msg void OnNcCalcSize(BOOL bCalcValidRects, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS FAR* lpncsp);
    afx_msg void OnNcPaint();
    afx_msg UINT OnGetDlgCode();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

/// IMPLEMENTATION /////////////////////////////////////////

CEditVC::CEditVC()
    : m_rectNCBottom(0, 0, 0, 0)
    , m_rectNCTop(0, 0, 0, 0)
{
}

CEditVC::~CEditVC()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEditVC, CEdit)
    ON_WM_NCCALCSIZE()
    ON_WM_NCPAINT()
    ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CEditVC::OnNcCalcSize(BOOL bCalcValidRects, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS FAR* lpncsp) 
{
    CRect rectWnd, rectClient;

    //calculate client area height needed for a font
    CFont *pFont = GetFont();
    CRect rectText;
    rectText.SetRectEmpty();

    CDC *pDC = GetDC();

    CFont *pOld = pDC->SelectObject(pFont);
    pDC->DrawText("Ky", rectText, DT_CALCRECT | DT_LEFT);
    UINT uiVClientHeight = rectText.Height();

    pDC->SelectObject(pOld);
    ReleaseDC(pDC);

    //calculate NC area to center text.

    GetClientRect(rectClient);
    GetWindowRect(rectWnd);

    ClientToScreen(rectClient);

    UINT uiCenterOffset = (rectClient.Height() - uiVClientHeight) / 2;
    UINT uiCY = (rectWnd.Height() - rectClient.Height()) / 2;
    UINT uiCX = (rectWnd.Width() - rectClient.Width()) / 2;

    rectWnd.OffsetRect(-rectWnd.left, -rectWnd.top);
    m_rectNCTop = rectWnd;

    m_rectNCTop.DeflateRect(uiCX, uiCY, uiCX, uiCenterOffset + uiVClientHeight + uiCY);

    m_rectNCBottom = rectWnd;

    m_rectNCBottom.DeflateRect(uiCX, uiCenterOffset + uiVClientHeight + uiCY, uiCX, uiCY);

    lpncsp->rgrc[0].top +=uiCenterOffset;
    lpncsp->rgrc[0].bottom -= uiCenterOffset;

    lpncsp->rgrc[0].left +=uiCX;
    lpncsp->rgrc[0].right -= uiCY;

}

void CEditVC::OnNcPaint() 
{
    Default();

    CWindowDC dc(this);
    CBrush Brush(GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));

    dc.FillRect(m_rectNCBottom, &Brush);
    dc.FillRect(m_rectNCTop, &Brush);
}

UINT CEditVC::OnGetDlgCode() 
{
    if(m_rectNCTop.IsRectEmpty())
    {
        SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }

    return CEdit::OnGetDlgCode();
}
```

I have the new CEdit inherited control created like this:

```
// Header File
CEditVC *mp_inputUser;

// Source File
OnInitDialog()
{
mp_inputUser = new CEditVC();
mp_inputUser->Create(WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, CRect(10,10,100,100), this, 1);
}
```

But the control shows no cursor and if I type a character it divorces itself into 2 pieces and acts very strange.

What could possibly cause this? Is there a later (better) version of doing this?

Comment: `top` - `bottom` = `106`. What other operations are you performing on `rectClient` between the call to `GetClientRect` and `ClientToScreen`? Are you sure these calls are being made on the correct/same window?

Comment: I didn't want to post the code again. I linked the answer with the code. There you can see what happens with the clientRect.

Comment: That just makes it less useful to people searching for a solution to this or similar problems. It also requires everyone that looks at your question to follow a link just to examine the code. Include the _relevant_ portions of code in your question and you reduce the amount of effort for _everyone else_.

Comment: Alright, sorry. I added the complete source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I just want to let you know that after lots of debugging I got behind the issue why the `OnNcCalcSize` method results in a strange output.

The OnNcCalcSize method gets called 3 times in an empty VS 2013 MFC project. The first two calls occur when there isnt even a dialog or CEditVC Control set up! That results in the ClientRect being 0,0,0,0. The code `UINT uiCenterOffset = (rectClient.Height() - uiVClientHeight) / 2;` will NOT work as expected as the calculated `uiVClientHeight` is something above 0 and is being subtracted from the clientRect height which is `0`. The UINT will overflow and every further use will result in undefined behaviour.

So to work around this issue in latest MFC projects I came up with:

```
void CEditVC::OnNcCalcSize(BOOL bCalcValidRects, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS FAR* lpncsp)
{
    CRect rectWnd, rectClient;

    GetClientRect(rectClient);

    // Workaround for calls with an empty Client Rect
    if (rectClient.Height() == 0)
    {
        CEdit::OnNcCalcSize(bCalcValidRects, lpncsp);
        return;
    }

    // Everything is back to default down here
    CFont *pFont = GetFont();
    CRect rectText;
    rectText.SetRectEmpty();

    CDC *pDC = GetDC();

    CFont *pOld = pDC->SelectObject(pFont);
    pDC->DrawText(L"Ky", rectText, DT_CALCRECT | DT_LEFT);
    UINT uiVClientHeight = rectText.Height();

    pDC->SelectObject(pOld);
    ReleaseDC(pDC);

    GetWindowRect(rectWnd);

    ClientToScreen(rectClient);

    UINT uiCenterOffset = (rectClient.Height() - uiVClientHeight) / 2;
    UINT uiCY = (rectWnd.Height() - rectClient.Height()) / 2;
    UINT uiCX = (rectWnd.Width() - rectClient.Width()) / 2;

    rectWnd.OffsetRect(-rectWnd.left, -rectWnd.top);
    m_rectNCTop = rectWnd;

    m_rectNCTop.DeflateRect(uiCX, uiCY, uiCX, uiCenterOffset + uiVClientHeight + uiCY);

    m_rectNCBottom = rectWnd;

    m_rectNCBottom.DeflateRect(uiCX, uiCenterOffset + uiVClientHeight + uiCY, uiCX, uiCY);

    lpncsp->rgrc[0].top += uiCenterOffset;
    lpncsp->rgrc[0].bottom -= uiCenterOffset;

    lpncsp->rgrc[0].left += uiCX;
    lpncsp->rgrc[0].right -= uiCY;
}
```

So I just added the if-statement on top to check if the function deals with an empty CRect and if that is the case, just use the base method of CEdit.

I suppose the class was written for old C++ MFC environments like VS6 when MFC or WinApi procedures were a little different...

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
ClientToScreen(rectClient);  // rectClient = {top=-2147483277 bottom=-2147483171 left=748 right=775}
```

You can see that:

```
bottom-top = (-2147483171)-(-2147483277) = 106
```

And

```
right-left = (775)-(748) = 27
```

Those values look familiar:

```
GetClientRect(rectClient);   // rectClient = {top=0 bottom=106 left=0 right=27}
```

So you have the same rectangle dimensions, the upper-left corner has simply been moved above and to the right of the top-left corner of the primary monitor.

If you have multiple monitors, remember that a monitor above the primary monitor has a negative `top` offset.  Is your window located on a secondary monitor that is above the primary monitor?

Comment: bottom-top = 106 and right-left = 27 still is strange as I created the CEditVC with the rect `CRect(10,10,100,100)`... The dimensions would be 90 for bottom-top and right-left, I think. And I have 2 monitors but its shown on the primary one :/