# In MFC how to vertically align text in edit box?

Tags: mfc

In my MFC dialog based application I want to align the text vertically in edit control.
My Edit control is not using WS_BORDER style.

The link [How can we vertically align text in edit box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867207/how-can-we-vertically-align-text-in-edit-box) gives solution for my problem and it is working for me.

That link is handling ON_WM_NCCALCSIZE() and ON_WM_NCPAINT() messages.I would like to know can I meet my requirement by overriding only onPaint() without overriding ON_WM_NCCALCSIZE() and ON_WM_NCPAINT() messages?

Comment: Overriding `OnPaint()` isn't enough because edit control also draws outside of `WM_PAINT` under certain conditions. Is there a situation where you cannot use the solution of the linked question? Otherwise this question will propably be closed as a dupe.

Comment: My superior asked me to check with OnPaint().

Comment: I suggest to ask for clarification by commenting the upvoted answer of the other question. That's certainly what I would do as this answer definitely lacks explanation (it's practically a code-only answer with non-trivial code which doesn't speak for itself). As it currently stands, the current question is not distinct enough for not being a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we vertically align text in edit box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867207/how-can-we-vertically-align-text-in-edit-box)

Comment: @user369287 tell your superiour that you have found a better solution than overriding OnPaint.

Comment: @zett42-My Edit control is not using WS_BORDER style so is it necessary to override the messages ON_WM_NCCALCSIZE() and ON_WM_NCPAINT().

Comment: Yes I think so, because the non-client area (calculated by `WM_NCCALCSIZE`) is what centers the text vertically in this solution. Whether the control has `WS_BORDER` or not doesn't matter.