# How to horizontally align a text at the middle of a static control in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a static control which needs to display a long string in multiline. The control is large enough to contain the text. But  when there is little text, it looks awkward to top aligned. I want the text to middle aligned and didn't find any property to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which control and does this answer your question? [How can we vertically align text in edit box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867207/how-can-we-vertically-align-text-in-edit-box)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I'm using a static control which is large enough to accommodate a lengthy string and it need to display left - horizontally, If there is a small text, then it should be displayed at left and middle of the static control

Comment: What do you mean by `it should be displayed at left and middle`? `left` or `middle`?

Comment: I meant that text should be left- aligned and it is at the middle, in relative to the height of static control.

Comment: @ManeeshaMR maybe you should [edit] the question and show some pictures.